# Need a plugin available in jquery to show hide

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone please provide me some pointers to slide window plugin, if any, available in jQuery. Basically, I need to implement the functionality of yahoo mail where in you can hide the advertisement pane displayed on the right side of the window on click of a button.

Any help on that is really appreciated

Thanks and Regards,
Manav

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Why a plugin? You can easily do this with traditional jquery.

Comment: Ok. Let me give a more detail on the requirements. I am currently working on a single page application that extensively uses Backbone.js, require.js, jQuery. On one of my pages, I want a small bar on the right most side which is initially collapsed and a small arrow pointing towards right is displayed. Once the user clicks on the arrow, that bar comes out and covers half of the screen now thereby adjusting the already full screen to its half and adjusting its contents relativelty. At this point of time, the user should be given an option to either collapse back the bar or expand it further

Answer (score 2):

If you had an element with the ID `panel` that would sit on the right of the screen, and you wanted to slide it to the right until it's not visible anymore, and then remove it, you could use jQuery's [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function to achieve that effect:

```
$('#panel').animate({'margin-left': width-of-the-panel}, function() {
    $('#panel').remove();
});
```

- `$('#panel')` obtains the element with the ID of `panel`
- `animate()` animates the provided properties of the element and calls a function when it's done
- `margin-left: width-of-the-panel` (replacing `width-of-the-panel` with the actual width of the panel, in pixels) will animate the CSS property `margin-left` until it has a value equal to that of the panel's width, effectively moving it to the right enough so it disappears off the screen
- `$('#panel').remove()` finally removes the element from the DOM

Comment: Some explination would go a long way here.

Comment: Thanks for the details. I am going to try this now and let you know if this works for me. I am a bit new to UI frameworks. It may take a little while to get into the concepts. Thanks a lot for line by line explanations. This really helps!!

Answer (score -2):

There are a lot of options. Open sourced free frameworks - [jQuery UI](http://api.jqueryui.com/) and its [Slider](http://jqueryui.com/slider/) or [Animate](http://jqueryui.com/animate/)

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    if ($("#element").width() > 0) {
      // slide in
      $("#element").animate({width: 0},1000);
    }
    else {
      // slide out
      $("#element").animate({width: 200},1000);
    }
});
```